# android <compatible-screen> tablet specific name

Tags: android

All my compatible screens are working fine with normal, large and so on...

I have a layout called "**layout-sw600dp**" which is especially for tablets, 7 inches. Works great.

**How can I set this in the manifest.xml?**

e.g.

```
    <screen android:screenSize="sw600dp" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
```

Will be the Definition sw600dp fine?

Thx for ur answers!

Comment: Are you developing for >Android 3.2 ? [Guide: Support Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) _Android 3.2 introduces new attributes: android:requiresSmallestWidthDp, android:compatibleWidthLimitDp, and android:largestWidthLimitDp_

Comment: Yes, but I think u dont get my question. LAyout directories are not the ptroblem, they are working. I just want to know if its possible to define "sw600dp" in the manifest instead of screenSize="large" or"xlarge" ?

Comment: If you go to link I provided on my previous comment. After that attributes the text says "If you're developing your application for Android 3.2 and higher, you should use these attributes to declare your screen size support, instead of the attributes based on generalized screen sizes." But it only works on recents versions.